# Probability P(at least two will be chosen)

Tags: probability

$P(A) = 0.55 , P(B) = 0.45, P(C) = 0.4$
$P(A∩B) = 0.25 , P(B∩C) = 0.15 , P(A∩C) = 0.2$
$P(A∩B∩C)  = 0.1$

$$(0.25+0.15+0.2)-2(0.1) = 0.4 $$

Is this the correct way to find out, if at least two options will be chosen out of the three?

Comment: Please, also add the idea of your try with words.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  It could just as easily have been described as $P(A\cap B\cap C) + P(A\cap B\cap C^c) + P(A\cap B^c\cap C)+P(A^c\cap B\cap C) = (0.1)+(0.25-0.1)+(0.2-0.1)+(0.15-0.1)$

Comment: Got it, Thank you !

Comment: Alternative: Let $~Q_1~$ denote $~A\cap B, ~ Q_2~$ denote $~A\cap C, ~Q_3~$ denote $~B\cap C.~$ Then you want (**loosely**) $~Q_1 + Q_2 + Q_3 - (Q_1 \cap Q_2) - (Q_1 \cap Q_3) - (Q_2 \cap Q_3) + (Q_1 \cap Q_2 \cap Q_3).$

Comment: Re previous comment, note that it more readily fits the model of $\sum_{1 \leq i_1 \leq n} A_{i_1} - \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 \leq n} A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2} + \cdots - \cdots.$  The idea is that if a specific region is present in exactly $k$ out of the $n$ sets, then that region is counted exactly $\sum_{j=1}^k (-1)^{(j-1)}\binom{k}{j}$ times.  By the binomial expansion of $[(-1) + (1)]^k = 0$, this means that each region that is present in exactly $k$ of the $n$ sets is (in effect) counted **once**, as required.